# Checking for EOF using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a project that involves extracting data from a database into a text file, and then ingesting it into Hadoop. So i want to create a shell script that NiFi can run to automatically to check if a text file is extracted and ingest it, but I need to make sure that the whole data has been extracted first before ingesting it. Meaning I would need to check that the text file has an EOF, how do I do that?

Don't have any code as of yet, I have very little knowledge writing shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the file, use a different name. Rename it to the expected name once the extraction is done. Then, the other process can start its work once the file exists.

Answer (score 1):

EOF is not something that actually gets put in the text file - in fact, there isn't really any EOF *value*. EOF or end-of-file is a condition that occurs when you try to consume input from a source that has none to give.

There is no general marker you can look for in your text files that will tell you whether they are complete. You'll need to make your script indicate when a given chunk of data has been extracted in some other way. There are many possibilities; you could change the name of the file [as choroba suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671347/56541), or you could create a lock file and remove it once the data extraction is done, or you could have your extraction program write a distinctive sequence of bytes to the file at the end, or so on.